# When did the names of scientists first become the names of scientific units?

Tags: terminology, discoveries, units, scientists

Many scientific units are named after scientists, for example,

- Tesla for magnetic flux
- Farad for capacitance
- Newton for force.

When did the tradition of naming scientific units begin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[History of the metric system - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_metric_system#The_first_structured_metric_system:_CGS) says:

> In 1861, Charles Bright and Latimer Clark proposed the names of ohm, volt, and farad in honour of Georg Ohm, Alessandro Volta and Michael Faraday respectively for the practical units based on the centimetre-gramme-second absolute system. This was supported by Thomson (Lord Kelvin). These names were later scaled for use in the Practical System. The concept of naming units of measure after noteworthy scientists was subsequently used for other units.

Comment: Nine points for pasting something off Wikipedia?

Comment: That's a tad negative isn't it? Not only does finding an answer take time, but why should we require good answers have hard work put in? What matters is that questions get answered.